# Use Threads in Midlet: how to listen to running thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me

in my class I have an inline thread in the constructor that loads objects from a remote site:

```
Thread readSite = new Thread(new Runnable() {       
    public void run() { 
        site.loadStuff();
    } 
});
readSite.start();
```

I want to display a 'loading' message until the thread is finished. So **before** the above code I show a loading message.

**After** the above code I show the screen in which I would like to continue.

The code looks like this:

```
showLoadingView(); //tells the user it is waiting

Thread readSite = new Thread(new Runnable() {       
    public void run() { 
        site.loadStuff();
    } 
});
readSite.start();

showStuffView(); //works with the data retrieved from the site instance
```

Now, the main thread of course continues and the **showStuffView()** is directly executed.

I can now let the main thread wait for the **readSite** Thread, but then the user cannot accept the connection request ('is it ok to use airtime?') that is shown to the user (because the responsible thread is asleep I guess).

On the other side, I cannot execute the **showStuffView()** from the **readSite** Thread.

I hope you guys can explain how to wait for this thread. I looked into synchronized, but couldn't really find a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common problem with threads and this particular problem you can solver with boolean variable. but for general purpose i think [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is good.